# Error: Network Error using fetch or axios for POST, PUT, DELETE Request in reactjs+NodejsBackend (Missing Allow origin Header)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

Hi guys I'm using Reactjs Frontent App which communicating with nodejs Backend server. So for now when i'm using the Ip adress of server to execute API in frontend side everthing work fine but if I'm switching to https using domain name only GET request are allow but all the others (POST, DELETE, PUT) not working and axios return me error like this  [the image of error using Axios error while execute api request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq9zV.png)

and now if I'm using fetch I have and error  like this :

> **TypeError: Failed to fetch**

for now i did a deep search in internet espacially in stackoverflow but all the answers that i've found have not help to resolved my problem because despite all the changes made the same error persist.

**this is the code I've tested in Backend Nodejs:**

**1- I've tested this code :**

```
   app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization')
    next()
})
```

**2- I've tested this code :**

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors())
```

***All this has had no effect!***

**this is the code I've tested in Fronted side in ReactJs :**

```
await axios.put(`${baseUrl}/users/updateProfil/${id}`, data, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' ,
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${JSON.parse(token)}`
          }
        })
        .then(res => res.data).catch((e)=>{
          alert(e);
            console.log(e)
        });
```

and no matter the modification I'm adding a have the same error :

```
 Error: Network Error
    at n.exports (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.g.onerror (xhr.js:84)
```

this is the code to update the profil of user :

```
router.put('/updateProfil/:id', async (req, res) => {
  var userId = req.params.id;
  var first_name = req.body.first_name;
  var last_name = req.body.last_name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var country = req.body.country;
  var city = req.body.city;
  var phone = req.body.phone;
  var sender_sms_name = req.body.sender_sms_name;
  if (
    email &&
    phone &&
    city &&
    country &&  
    first_name &&
    last_name && 
    sender_sms_name
  )  {
    var user = await User.findOne({
      $or: [{ phone: phone }, { email: email }],
    }).select('-password').catch((error) => {
      res.status(404).json({
        success: false,
        val: 0,
        data: "error",
        message: "Something went wrong.",
      });
    }); 
    if (user != null) {
       await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {
        first_name: first_name,
        email: email,
        last_name: last_name,
        phone: phone,
        city: city,
        country: country,
        sender_sms_name: sender_sms_name}, {new: true})
      .then( async(user) => {
        user= await User.populate(user, {path: 'sub_account'})
        return res.status(200).json({
          success: true,
          val: 1,
          data: user,
          message: "update done ",
        });
      });
    }else{
      return res.status(404).json({
        success: true,
        val: 1,
        data: "error while updating",
        message: "update success ! ",
      });
    }
   
  }else {
    return res.status(404).json({
      success: false,
      val: 0,
      data: "impossible to update!",
      message: "verify fields please.",
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: And does it work with postman?

Comment: no   even with postman the request fails

Comment: can you share the code of the server ? where is the code that run when accessing the endpoint `updateProfil` ?

Comment: modify my question and i added the endpoint  updateProfil up there